# Time control in Universal Tween Engine

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
Timeline.createSequence()
.push(Tween.set(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager))
.push(Tween.set(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager))

.push(Timeline.createParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA,0.5f).delay(0.5f).target(1).start(tweenManager))
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA,0.5f).delay(0.3f).target(1).start(tweenManager))   
    .start(tweenManager)
    )

.pushPause(1)

.push(Timeline.createParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(10,10).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(20,20).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    .start(tweenManager)
    )

.pushPause(1)

.push(Timeline.createParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(100,100).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(200,200).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    .start(tweenManager)
    )
.start(tweenManager);
```

Hi, I am new in programming. I am making an animation using tween engine.

It should be like this:

First, 2 cups appear at (100, 100) and (200, 200) respectively at the same time.
A second later, 2 cups move to (10, 10) and (20, 20) respectively at the same time.
Finally, they move back to their original position at the same time.returns

However, the 3 steps happen at the same time and ignore the pushPause.
How can I correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you call `.start(tweenManager)` into inner declarations that triggers each of 3 sequential animations to run immediately.

Your code should look so:

```
Timeline.createSequence()
.push(Tween.set(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager))
.push(Tween.set(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager))

.push(Timeline.createParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA,0.5f).delay(0.5f).target(1).start(tweenManager))
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA,0.5f).delay(0.3f).target(1).start(tweenManager))   
    )

.pushPause(1)

.push(Timeline.createParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(10,10).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(20,20).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    )

.pushPause(1)

.push(Timeline.createParallel()
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop1, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(100,100).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    .push(Tween.to(cuptop2, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 1.0f).target(200,200).ease(TweenEquations.easeNone).start(tweenManager))
    )

.start(tweenManager);
```

Comment: Oh yes! That's the problem is.
Also, I should delete all the .start(tweenManager); behind Tween.to() method. Thank you so much:)